# Vuetify 2->3 v-text-field child alignment (prepend-inner and append seem to be ignored)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm working on migrating some legacy code from Vuetify 2 to 3. Currently, I'm having trouble with `v-text-field` child components. I've tried a number of things based on other StackOverflow posts or Google hits, but none of them seem to solve the problem, just move the label text around. Most of the posts/GitHub issues I've found seem to be alignment issues of the label itself (like wanting it on the right side), not an issue where components are overlapping each other.

The old version of our `FilterPanel` component looked like this:
[image: Vuetify 2]
But the Vuetify 3 version I've been working on has some serious layout issues:
[image]

For whatever reason, the text input is to the *right* of the `append` 'add filter' button, and the label is hidden behind the `prepend-inner` `v-select`

I tried changing `append` to `append-inner`, but that didn't seem to make any difference. Similarly with changing `prepend-inner` to `prepend`. I also tried adding a label INSIDE the label, thinking that might help, but it didn't render, regardless of what slot I tried using.

One other unanswered question - in Vuetify 2, what exactly did `menu-props='auto'` do? I see it's not supported in Vuetify 3, even as `menu-props="{ auto: true }"`, but I can't find any real documentation on what auto used to do, so I have no idea whether it's related to my visual issue, or whether I can just remove that bit.

Also, there's a `v-chip` after the `v-text-field` but I don't think that's related, so I've omitted it. I also stripped off style and event handlers from this snippet, since they don't seem to impact layout.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="text"
      name="text"
      label="Type your filter here"
      hide-details
      variant="solo"
      density="compact"
      theme="dark"
    >
      <v-select
        slot="prepend-inner"
        v-model="field"
        :items="fields"
        :menu-props="{ auto: true }"
        label="Field"
        hide-details
        single-line
        density="compact"
        variant="solo"
        theme="dark"
      >
        <v-field rounded flat />
      </v-select>

      <v-btn slot="append" color="normal" size="small">
        Add Filter
        <v-icon end theme="dark"> mdi-filter-plus </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm at a point where I'm thinking maybe what I should do is use a `v-container`/`v-row`/`v-col`, since I imagine that would let me force the desired layout, but I'd prefer to avoid that path if it's possible. (Not to mention, there seem to be some style issues doing that. See below.) If I replace the `v-text-field` with `<v-container><v-row>`, then put the original `v-text-field` in-between the `v-select` and `v-btn`, it looks closer, but still doesn't look right:
[image]

Finally, if instead of replacing `v-text-field` with `v-container`, I add *another* `v-text-field` inside and add `display="none"` to the outer text field... it shows the label in the right place, but still tries to do input on the right hand side:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning is not working because you are using deprecated slot syntax:

```
slot="prepend-inner" ...
```

is now

```
v-slot:prepend-inner>
```

or the short-hand

```
#prepend-inner
```

also, you have to put the slot declaration on a template, it does not work on components directly anymore:

```html
<template v-slot:prepend-inner>
  <v-select
    ...
```

With this, the slots work, however, nesting the VSelect in a VTextField does not seem to work, looks like the text field does not allow to open the select. Also, there is an issue with spacing. I am pretty sure there are more problems. I think, even with the slots, you will have to build it another way.

Have a look at it on [the playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

When the [`:auto`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-auto) prop is set the select menu will be positioned so that the selected item  is positioned where the select box is. So instead of dropping up or dropping down, the menu opens in both directions. Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/bl1rt/pen/QWZYqPN?editors=101) if it helps, just look at where the menu opens depending on the selected item.